# Type of printf width specifier

Tags: c, printf

What should the type of `width` be in the following call?

```
snprintf(buf, buflen, "%.*s", width, astring);
```

How can I specify `width` to work correctly on both 32 and 64-bit platforms?

Is width limited to `2**32` on 64-bit platforms?

Comment: `width` must be `int` [see this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25366k66.aspx).

Comment: Is `2**32` (actually `2**31-1`) characters not wide enough for you ?

Comment: if `INT_MAX` is not enough, you can of course achieve the same effect without using `snprintf`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I specify `width` to work correctly on both 32 and 64-bit platforms?

Insure `width` is type `int`.

In this case, code uses a *precision* field, `"%.*s"`, which is also `int`.

---

> Is width limited to 2**32 on 64-bit platforms?

Anything more than 4095 may run into issues:

1. The issue is the range of `int`, not the platform bit width.
2. The width of a single conversion may be limited:

> **Environmental limits** The number of characters that can be produced by any single conversion shall be at least **4095**.  C11 §7.21.6.1 15

3. The return value of `int snprintf()` is the number of characters printed.  A call that attempts to print more than `INT_MAX` *total* characters may fail.

<strike>4. Detail: As used in `snprintf(buf, buflen, "%.*s", width, astring);`, `width` is the *minimum* characters to print, padding with spaces as needed.</strike>

Comment: I wonder about your comment 4.: what I get from GCC: `%*s` -- never truncate, pad to the right; `%.*s` -- truncate, never pad; `% *s` -- compile-time warnings.

Comment: @qama face-palm: I was (incorrectly) stating something about the width field and not the precision field as the post uses.

Answer (score 1):

The width is going to work on all platforms if you declare it to be an `int`. The actual size of the `int` is platform-dependent.

The type to be passed for the asterisk is specified in the C99 standard, section 7.19.6.1.5:

> Field width, or precision, or both, may be indicated by an asterisk. In this case, an `int` argument supplies the field width or precision. The arguments specifying field width, or precision, or both, shall appear (in that order) before the argument (if any) to be converted. A negative field width argument is taken as a - flag followed by a positive field width.

As long as you declare `int width`, your code is going to work properly on all standard-compliant platforms.

> Is width limited to 2<sup>32</sup> on 64-bit platforms?

The size of `int` is implementation-specific. It may be 32 bits on 64-bit platforms, in which case the width would be limited to 2<sup>31</sup>-1, because negative numbers are interpreted differently.

Comment: Does that mean, that `LLP64` and `LP64` data models impose a limit on width length, meaning that it's not possible to give 64-bit width argument to `*printf`?

Comment: @qarma Yes, both LLP64 and LP64 [use 32-bit integers](https://blogs.oracle.com/nike/entry/ilp64_lp64_llp64). Only ILP64 uses 64-bit integers.

Comment: And once you want to output that amount of characters, you certainly won't be using printf().

Comment: Thanks, @joop I wanted to be sure I could use pointer arithmetic, like `width = ptr1 - ptr2` where the latter is result of, e.g. `strchr()`.

Comment: Don't do that. Or use a cast `(int)( ptr1-ptr2)` to force the argument to printf to be an actual int. (since they cannot infer them, vararg functions rely on the proper types being passed)